# Not getting full profile info from linkedin python

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to get all the info I can from a public profile. Linkedin says that I should be able to get:

```
<id>
<first-name>
<last-name>
<headline>
<location>
  <name>
  <country>
    <code>
  </country>
</location>
<industry>
 <current-status>
<current-status-timestamp>
<connections total="" >
<summary/>
<positions total="">
  <position>
    <id>
    <title>
    <summary>
    <start-date>
      <year>
      <month>
    </start-date>
    <is-current>
    <company>
      <name>
    </company>
  </position>
</positions>
```

I am only able to get

```
<headline>
<first-name>
<last-name>
```

please let me know how to change my code:

```
CONSUMER_KEY = '9pux1XXXXXX'     # This is api_key
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'brtXoXXXXXXX'   # This is secret_key

USER_TOKEN = '27138ae8-5XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'   # This is oauth_token
USER_SECRET = 'ca103e23-4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'   # This is oauth_secret
RETURN_URL = 'http://localhost:8000'

from linkedin import linkedin
from oauthlib import *

# Define CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,  
# USER_TOKEN, and USER_SECRET from the credentials 
# provided in your LinkedIn application

# Instantiate the developer authentication class

authentication = linkedin.LinkedInDeveloperAuthentication(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, 
                                                      USER_TOKEN, USER_SECRET, 
                                                      RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())

# Pass it in to the app...

application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)

# Use the app....

a = application.get_profile(member_url='http://www.linkedin.com/pub/louis-litt/56/464/816')
```

When I run the program, all I get is:

```
{u'headline': u'Senior Associate at Pearson Hardman', u'lastName': u'Litt', u'siteStandardProfileRequest': {u'url': u'http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=198202770&authType=name&authToken=yIgW&trk=api*a295771*s303335*'}, u'firstName': u'Louis'}
```

Comment: If the documentation for LinkedInApplication.get_profile doesn't specify any other call parameters, then get support from linkedin (assuming they wrote the library).

Comment: @dilbert I tried getting their support. Posted a question on their site....no response, but it's only been a day

Answer (score 1):

Linkedin has now restricted access for program developers, so basically you can only choose from the following 4 aspects r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress, rw_company_admin, w_share

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the public profile for a user, which will only yield certain fields, depending on what the user has chose to display on his public profile, and on LinkedIn's settings.

Try to grab your own profile `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~` , you should be able to retrieve all the fields.

Comment: when I grab my own profile, it still returns the same limited info

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make sense. What is the profile URL you're using to grab your own profile?

Comment: a = application.get_profile()   this will get your own profile